# JACOB throws EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, jvm, activex, jacob

We are getting EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error on our windows server, but we are not able replicate/reproduce this error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180012df1, pid=1604, tid=4232
#
# JRE version: 7.0_07-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jacob-1.14.3-x64.dll+0x12df1]  Java_com_jacob_com_Variant_getVariantType+0x51
#
# Core dump written. Default location: c:\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\hs_err_pid1604.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

We are using Java version 1.7, Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise and Jacob-1.14.3. I am assuming that the error is because of Jacob-1.14.4.dll but not sure why its causing the issue. If I upgrade to latest Jacob-18M.jar will solve the issue? Can someone confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Crew, Any updates on my above query?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my project and it was solved after some months investigating all of our environment, If anyone still needs it here is the link.
[EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Jacob dll using VM in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125191/exception-access-violation-in-jacob-dll-using-vm-in-jenkins-pipeline)

There we have the description of all the  things we have tried.